# RevealViewController is nil works fine for other file

Tags: ios, swift

I am stuck for a week on this and have looked everywhere. RevealViewController is nil and the Menu doesn't open instead it goes to home view. The same code and outlets work fine on other files.

```
 if(self.revealViewController() != nil){

            settingsButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
            settingsButton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: "revealToggle:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            self.revealViewController().delegate = self

            view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

            let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer()
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        }
```

This same code works for other file which i have implemented. 
P.S I am opening SWRevealViewController.

Comment: What does `self.revealViewController()` do?  How does the controller you're checking for get initialized?

Comment: RevealViewController is a child controller which lets you access SWRevealViewController.

Comment: Sure, but I repeat, what happens in the function you call and how is the controller initialized?

Comment: You want to see the code inside the function?   UIViewController *parent = self;
    Class revealClass = [SWRevealViewController class];
    while ( nil != (parent = [parent parentViewController]) && ![parent isKindOfClass:revealClass] ) {}
    return (id)parent;

Comment: So, if you print out the class of each of the parents in the `while`, what do you see?

Comment: It's giving me nil.

Comment: I guess your controller isn't contained by a `SWRevealViewController` then.  (In fact, if all you get is a single `nil`, it doesn't seem your controller is contained by anything.)

Comment: How do I do it? Since the same code works for other storyboards. That's the main problem. If you have time can you check the problem on TeamViewer?

Comment: I suspect you're correct.  It's not a code problem; it's likely about how the controllers are connected to each other.

Comment: Yeah. I have many times checked the controllers connection. It's still not solving.

Answer (score 0):

Check your segue's identifiers. It must be "sw_front"and "sw_rear" because SWRevealViewController configure with this identifier name.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean from the button I am making the segue? To toggle to sw_rear ?

Comment: Yes, from where you want to open Slide menu.

Comment: Nothing happens if i gave the segue identifier sw_rear. The button doesn't lead you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to the menu page then connect it with swrevealviewcontrtoller I too had the same prob this solved mine and you can use [self.revealviewcontroller panGestureRecogonizer]; instead of [self.view addgesture:self.revealviewcontroller.panGestureRecogoniser];
adding subviews may cause this problem!!

Comment: The issue is which i am getting now is my parentviewcontroller is being nil.

Comment: @HumayunKhan can u explain I am not able to understand your problem

Comment: have u checked your connection ???did u connect it to sw reveal view controller??

Comment: @HumayunKhan if you can screenshot ur storyboard or if possible send me ur project let me check it!!  email-akshay1318a@gmail.com

Comment: Nope not yet. I haven't worked it on, been busy with other tasks